# How in VBA to find and highlight the latest date out of a column for each set of common values in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of order numbers in column A, some are unique but many are repeated in multiple rows.  For those orders where there are multiple entries in column A I would like to evaluate the dates in another column, B and highlight (set the interior color) the latest one.  Some of the date entries in column B are blank and I'd like to ignore those in the evaluation.  My sheet would then have the cells highlighted for the latest entry for any multiple order.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? SO is not a "code for me" service. If you show us your efforts, we can guide you down the right path. Personally, I like to use dictionaries for sorting out duplicates, or finding maximums. I'm also wondering if this can't just be done with conditional formatting.

Comment: Also an excerpt of the data would be nice. The description is very difficult to understand.